# How can I deploy this task to my customer?

Tags: c#, deployment

I have been working on a task from customer where I generate `XML` files, sign them and forward them to a `web service`.

The `signature` uses `PKCS11` standard and uses a `smart card` to sign the document.

The `app` itself is on the `server` and the part where I sign and save the `XML` is `Published` on the `client` machine.

It saves the document to the `client's` desktop folder, however, the `signature` part is not allowed - it always says the same thing:

> The operation was canceled by the user.

I have a `console app` which successfully signs the `XMLs`, however, I am unable to run the `.exe` file using `CMD` or `Powershell` - they are not even opened on the client's machine.

How can I proceed with this?

The only thing I can think of is create another `web application` that is hosted on the client machine and looks at the folder where the `XMLs` are generated lists them, signs them and forwards them to the `web service`.

The problem is - it makes it `two clicks` for the customer - one to generate the `XMLs`, other is to choose them and `sign them`.

Is there any better suggestion? Are there alternatives to Publish, or any other way I can deliver this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and create a .bat file that opens the files. For example:
If you're XML file is on your desktop, create a .bat file anywhere on your computer and type the path in the file. In my case i put a .txt file in my debug folder. This is the example of my .bat file:

```
@echo off
Y:\Documents\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\test.txt
```

Now you can start this bat file from you're console application. Make sure you have the following import:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Then create a process that opens the .bat file. In my case this is my method:

```
private static void Run()
{
    Process.Start(@"Y:\Documents\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\start.bat");
}
```

Hope this helps you :)

Good luck,

Twan